# Understanding root and tk.Frame in tkinter

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter

The example below has previously been used to describe the functionality of classes and switching pages in Tkinter.
Although I don't understand:

1. Why classes PageOne and PageTwo need to inherit from tk.Frame?
2. Where the equivilant of root = Tk() is (since in other beginner tutorials I watched, this step is essential).

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"))
        button1.pack()
        button2.pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"Why tk.Frame needs to be passed into and initialised in PageOne and PageTwo "_ - `tk.Frame` isn't being passed in anywhere. Are you asking why they _inherit_ from `tk.Frame`?

Comment: _"Where the equivilant of root = Tk() is"_ - that would be `app = SampleApp()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley, yes sorry, I have rephrased my first question. How does SampleApp() serve the same purpose as Tk()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why classes PageOne and PageTwo need to inherit from tk.Frame?

They don't have to inherit from `tk.Frame`. Because they contain other widgets, `tk.Frame` is the natural choice. You could use `tk.Canvas` or literally any other widget (though, using widgets like `tk.Button` or `tk.Scrollbar` make no sense)

> Where the equivilant of root = Tk()

It is this line of code:

```
app = SampleApp()
```

`SampleApp` inherits from `tk.Tk`, so it behaves exactly the same. You're free to rename `app` to `root` if you wish.